# What features does each coefficient in dual_coef_ correspond to for the polynomial kernel?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I trained a simple quadratic SVM using sklearn.svm.SVC on 3 features. In other words, X is nx3, Y is length n and I simply ran the following code with no problem:

```
svc = SVC(kernel='poly', degree = 2)
svc.fit(X,Y)
```

As my goal is to plot this boundary in 3D, I am trying to figure out which features each of the resulting coefficients correspond to. Naturally, a quadratic function with 3 features will result in an intercept term and 10 coefficients where each coefficient corresponds to:

```
x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x1x2, x1x3, x2x3, x1x2x3, x1, x2, x3
```

However, `svc.dual_coef` returns an array of the 10 coefficients but I do not know which of them correspond to which of the 10 features, is there a way to figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't seem to find an answer to this. In fact, a lot of people are saying that this is tricky. Why not build the polynomial features in advance using [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), and use a linear svm?

Comment: I ended up solving the weights for the primal problem by using the dual coefficients, support vectors and feature mapping vector Phi. After that, I solve for x3 given a mesh grid of x1 X x2 using the closed form quadratic solution. This allows you to plot the SVC with quadratic kernel in 3D space. I guess it makes sense why the developers did not include the primal weights in the "degree = 2" case because it's only one case. For degree >=3 it becomes extremely difficult if not impossible to solve explicitly.